# glisten Dialog resize issue

Tags: gluon-mobile

I got a strange layout issue with the gluon dialog class.
I'm creating a new Dialog instance and adding some containers, at the end some simple buttons.

Dialog
 - Anchorpane
   - VBox
     - GridPane
       - A Bunch of buttons

[image: This is how it looks]

So the problem is that the Dialog Container itself is not resized to fit its children. Do you have any hints for me where there might be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the `Dialog` padding is not taken into account. So as a quick workaround you could remove the padding from the dialog and add it to the dialog content node:

```
//in css   
.dialog {
    -fx-padding: 0.0;
}

//or 
    public class DialogTest<T> extends Dialog<T> {

        public DialogTest() {
            rootNode.setStyle("-fx-padding:0;");
        }
    }

//...
  anchorPane.setPadding(new Insets(top, right, bottom, left));
```

Comment: Perfectly working now. Didn't realized that it was cause of the padding. Thank you for the quick reply with the solution.